# Static binding and dynamic binding with no methods

Tags: java, dynamic-binding, late-static-binding

I had an exam in my college on objected-oriented programming. One of the questions was about static binding and dynamic Binding.

The question was as follows:

```
Shape s; if(i==1) s = new Point(1,2); else s = new Rectange(10,20); //this is dynamic binding.
```

**YES/NO**
[image]
it's not my answer btw.

My teacher said the answer is "no" because it's **static binding.**

As I know static binding and dynamic binding happen only when I call methods. I read all the StackOverflow questions and a lot of blog posts about this topic and the only answer I can come up with is that there is **dynamic binding**.

Any explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: You hardcoded that `s` refers either to a `Point` or to a `Rectangle` instance ... what is _dynamic_ about that?

Comment: This is only a guess, but maybe what your teacher meant is that the possible types are known at compile time. There's no way to introduce a new, unknown type at runtime, as there would be if you used reflection to instantiate an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"binding" just means you're associating a name with an object, so there is binding going on here.

This is dynamic binding, see [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_binding):

> The binding of names before the program is run is called static (also "early"); bindings performed as the program runs are dynamic (also "late" or "virtual").
>
> An example of a static binding is a direct C function call: the function referenced by the identifier cannot change at runtime.
>
> But an example of dynamic binding is dynamic dispatch, as in a C++ virtual method call. Since the specific type of a polymorphic object is not known before runtime (in general), the executed function is dynamically bound.

Even though the posted code predetermines what s gets set to by setting i, what makes this dynamic is that methods called on s will get resolved at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's dynamic binding.

The value of i variable is not known at compile time. Depending on value of i variable at run time, Shape has been set. As Nathan Hughes suggested, the methods called on Shape are resolved at runtime, which makes it late dynamic binding.